# Why padding doesn't work right after margin property?

Tags: html, css

```
div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 4px solid #ff0000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #308014;
  margin: 20px 50px 10px 5px
  padding: 40px;

  /*padding-top: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  */
}
```

Like in this code example padding won't work, nothings happen. But if I put it before margin property (after background-color) it will work fine. What is the reason of this? Thanks.

Comment: hardest question ever answered:))

Comment: You have `padding: 40;` + content height that must be over `90px` `height` and you set `height: 50px;` on element. That cant be good

Comment: @NenadVracar Yes it can. The `height` property does not include the margin, padding or border. So in this case the _total_ height would amount to 168 pixels.

Comment: @Mr Lister You are right but take a look at this example with boostrap and `border-box` sizing and see what happens with height when you uncomment it https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/112/.

Comment: @NenadVracar I know about the box-sizing property, yes. If that was your concern, that's what you should have said. The default value for box-sizing on a div is padding-box, so your remark "That can't be good" lacked context.

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple typographical mistake of missing a `;` after margin property.

```
div 
{
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 4px solid #ff0000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #308014;
  margin: 20px 50px 10px 5px;
  padding: 40px;
  /*
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    padding-left: 40px;
  */
}
```

Comment: lol, so awkward mistake. Thanks, now everythings works fine  despite their order